# The real numbers $w, x, y, z$ satisfy the equalities $w+x+y+z=0$ and $w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Prove that $-1\le wx+xy+yz+zw\le0$

Tags: inequality, optimization

The real numbers $w, x, y, z$ satisfy the equalities $w+x+y+z=0$ and $w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Prove that $-1\le wx+xy+yz+zw\le0$

Supposing $wx+xy+yz+zw>0$. I've proven via contradiction that $wx+xy+yz+zw\le0$.

But suppose $wx+xy+yz+zw<-1$. Then $wx+xy+yz+zw+1<0$. I'm not sure how to factorise the LHS.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `algebraic-number-theory`?

Comment: @Atticus Thanks, correct is by Cauchy-Schwarz: $$\lvert wx+xy+yz+zw\rvert\le (w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2)=1$$ hence $wx+xy+yz+zw\geq-1$. In fact, $x+y+z+w=0$ is *not needed* for this part

Answer (score 2):

Because $$\sum_{cyc}xy=(x+z)(w+y)=-(x+z)^2\leq0$$ and 
$$1+\sum_{cyc}xy=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x+y)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Is there a logic applicable to $n \ge 5$ numbers, for the first inequality?

Comment: @Siddharth Joshi For $n\geq5$ it's much more harder.

Answer (score 0):

We have $a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab$ for any two real numbers $a$ and $b$. So

$$
\begin{aligned}
0=(x+y+z+w)^2 &= x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+2(xy+yz+zw+wx)+2(xz+wy) \\
&=1+2(xy+yz+zw+wx)+2(xz+wy) \\
&\leq 1+2(xy+yz+zw+wx)+(x^2+z^2+y^2+w^2) \\
&=2+2(xy+yz+zw+wx) 
\end{aligned}
$$

It follows that

$$-1 \leq xy+yz+zx+zw$$

Equality is achieved when $y=w$ and $x=z$.

This gives two equality cases $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}, -\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2}, -\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2}, -\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Also for $\le 0$ we can use the same approach: $|xz+wy|\le\frac{w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2}2=\frac12$ hence $xy+yz+zw+wx=-\frac12-xz-wy\le 0$